# Calculate opposite percentage

Tags: percentages

This is a bit of a strange question, I came up with a simple analogy.

Say I have test results, for a group of students. And percentage of students passed is $p$, failed is $f$.

I want to calculate the value of $p$ from $f$, bear in mind they are both percentages. Say $p$ is 25%, then $f$ would be 75%. How could I calculate this with $p$ as any real number?

EDIT: $100 - p = f$
*sigh*

Comment: Well, all students compose 100% of the students, and you're dividing them into two groups, so....

Comment: Hold on i've just realized. That's why you always ask, you realize as soon as you ask.

Comment: Glad you could find an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Percentages add up to 100, so 100 - p = f